# Microsoft Access runtime error DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext

Tags: ms-access, runtime-error

I have been trying to get a set of buttons beneath a form for the simplicity for the users.  Only the issue i get with the scripting is that i am not able to get the next record button to work. Here I get a Runtime Error 2105.

What it is suppose to do is show only the next existing record, but instead is gives a runtime error and skips all the other records and goes to the last one.

Any ideas of what i am doing wrong?

```
If Me.ActiveXBestEl92.Enabled = False Then
    Me.ActiveXBestEl92.Enabled = True
    End If

With Recordset
  If .AbsolutePosition = .RecordCount Then


  Me.ActiveXBestEl93.Enabled = False
      Else


DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext


  End If
End With

Exit_Next_Record:
    Me.ActiveXBestEl93.Enabled = False

Exit Sub

Err_Next_Record:

MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Next_Record
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
With Me.RecordsetClone
    If .AbsolutePosition = .RecordCount Then
        Me!ActiveXBestEl93.Enabled = False
    Else
        .MoveNext
    End If
End With
```

or this:

```
With Me.RecordsetClone
    If Me.CurrentRecord = .RecordCount Then
        Me!ActiveXBestEl93.Enabled = False
    Else
        .MoveNext
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Sorry, But it didnt work, The issue is now diffrent.. it shows all the records and goes automaticly to the next one. The AbsolutePosition stays -1 for every record. So the error gives Error 3021, No current record

Comment: It didnt like the .MoveNext, So i took the whole consept and put it together. now it seems to work with over 1000 records without an Issue